# Debian Loding Linux 701... error: invalid magic number

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub, gnu-screen

Yesterday before going to bed debian wanted make an update when I tried to close my computer. When I about to do the update the computers battery died, and I went to sleep. Today when I tried to boot my computer normally it said `Loding Linux 701... error: invalid magic number` When I click `*Debian GNU/Linux` on the GNU GRUB bootloader screen, and just sends me back to the same screen when I click something. I can open my computer by going `Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux` and selecting something other than linux 701 which I tried: `Debian GNU/Linux with Linux 5.10.0-21-amd64`. I tried updating when accessed my pc but it didn't update when I powered it off and is still giving me the same error. I can't even boot 701 on recovery mode, it gives the same error. How can I fix this to access Linux 701 without losing my stuff inside the computer? Also I have pick advanced settings each time I boot which is kinda annoying...

Comment: what is "Linux 701"? Never heard of it, and google search is a bust - perhaps grub loader is messed up, try `update-grub`, perhaps that'll fix it

Comment: @JaromandaX How do I update it? Maybe it's refering to linux 7.10 if thats a thing? Considering 5.10 linux kernel version is a thing.

Comment: well, you update it by running update-grub when you've booted into 5.10 ... and no, Linux 701 has nothing to do with linux 7.10 because there is not linux 7.10 and 701 is not 7.10 anyway - so, when you do boot in, what's the content of `/boot` folder?

Comment: @JaromandaX I ran it (forgot to use sudo the first time), I'll see if the problem persists. On my `/boot` folder I only got files about 5.10,`efi` and `grub` folders. And an executable (application/x-executable) called `kernel-701`.